# SDL_RWread return string with segmentation fault

Tags: c++, sdl

Can't use string variable to save/load as file by SDL_RWwrite/SDL_RWread.

```
// Save data
SDL_RWops* storeDataFile = SDL_RWFromFile("data.bin", "w+b");
if(storeDataFile != NULL) {
  string sStoreString = "Hello World";
  SDL_RWwrite(storeDataFile, &sStoreString, sStoreString.size(), 1);
  SDL_RWclose(storeDataFile);
}

// Load data
SDL_RWops* storeDataFile = SDL_RWFromFile("data.bin", "r+b");
if(storeDataFile != NULL) {
  string sStoreString;
  SDL_RWread(storeDataFile, &sStoreString, storeDataFile->size(storeDataFile), 1);
  SDL_RWclose(storeDataFile);

  cout << sStoreString << endl;
}
```

That last cout line will give segmentation fault error.
If replace string by int, then it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `sStoreString.c_str()` rather than `&sStoreString`.

Otherwise you're accessing not the string contents, but fields of the `std::string` class.

Comment: Thank you. This makes file saves in text mode, I can change it to char[] to read file content. Still, any way to save/load as string binary (like int variable)?

Comment: @Skarpeys What do you mean by *"as string binary"*? Are you asking how to load such file into a `std::string`?

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood about binary file save. This problem is already solved - thank to you.

Comment: @Skarpeys If so, I suggest pressing the green tick on the left of the answer to mark your problem as solved. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers